# How to update the scope variable outside an XMLHttprequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jszip

I am trying to get the file contents of a css file and trying to store it in a variable which I am going to use later.I am using XMLHttprequest to get the contents of the file.When I tried putting console inside the onreadystatechange the output is coming perfectly ,but when tried the same thing outside of it it's showing empty result in the variable.I have heard about $apply and other stuff,but is there an another way to make this happen,where am I going wrong?...Thanks in advance...
This is the code

```
    $scope.files={};
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/your_css/bootstrap.css');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      var bootstrap=client.responseText;
      css.file("bootstrap.css",bootstrap);
      $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
          $scope.files.bootstrap=bootstrap;
        })
     }
     client.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AngularJS $http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which wraps the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) and is integrated with the AngularJS framework:

```
$http.get('/your_css/bootstrap.css').then(function (response) {
    $scope.files.bootstrap = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the behavior you just described is that `onreadystatechange` is not executed, just defined. `client.send()` is sending a request to extract a file and `onreadystatechange` is only executed when the response (and the file) arrived to the browser. "After" `onreadystatechange` is only positionally after, but in terms of time it is before that. `onreadystatechange` is a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). You wanted your [asynchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) to behave synchronously, but that is a bad idea and a bad design. I recommend you to get used to asynchronous requests, because waiting for a request to be finished on client-side is a bad idea and it gets worse if you have several requests, all of them executed synchronously. It would really hurt performance.